# Issue with Javascript Stopwatch counter

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

I have this time counter in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/oukjfavu/718/#

How do I remove the "minutes" part of the counter in h1 because I only need the seconds and millisecond section?

```
function format(ms) {
  var d = new Date(ms + t[5]).toString()
    .replace(/.*([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]).*/, '$1');
  var x = String(ms % 1000);
  while (x.length < 3) x = '0' + x;
  d += '.' + x;
  h1.textContent = d
  return d;
}
```

when I remove the minute part of the counter:

```
.replace(/.*([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]).*/, '$1');
```

to this

```
.replace(/.*[0-9][0-9]).*/, '$1');
```

The second counter won't update.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shorter version

```js
var startTime = Date.now();

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
    var time = (elapsedTime / 1000).toFixed(3).toString();
    time = time.replace('.', ':');
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = time;
}, 1);
```

```css
#timer {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Comment: If you want more precision you can change the 100 before the last bracket to 1 @JesseLimJiaNian

Comment: @mrid Oh, thanks. But the millisecond looks choppy. How do I  increase the interval rate higher?

Comment: @mrid Oh, thanks. Just integrate in my project and works fine